# using preg_replace_callback for multiple matches

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I tried a simple regex using `preg_replace_callback` as

```
$str = 'Key Value';
$str = preg_replace_callback('/(key) (.*?)/', function($m) { 
return $m[2].$m[1];
}, $str);

echo $str;
```

I expected the output would be

```
ValueKey
```

but it doesn't. Where did I make the mistake?

Comment: `(.*?)` matches nothing when at the end of the pattern. Did you want `'/(key) (.*)/'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to remove `?` after `*` in the pattern. Otherwise it'll stop matching as soon as possible (i.e. after none characters).

Second. You either have to use case insensitive matching, adding `i` parameter, or change the case of word `key` in the pattern:

```
<?php
$str = 'Key Value';
$str = preg_replace_callback('/(key) (.*)/i', function($m) { 
return $m[2].$m[1];
}, $str);

echo $str; // ValueKey
```